# Can't install Perl module Apache::SizeLimit on CentOS

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, perl, mod-perl

On a CentOS machine I have installed mod_perl:

```
yum install mod_perl
...
Package mod_perl-2.0.4-10.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
```

Ok, now I want to install the Perl module Apache::SizeLimit, so I do (and get):

```
yum install perl-Apache-SizeLimit
...
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Check Error:
file /usr/share/man/man3/Apache2::SizeLimit.3pm.gz from install of perl-Apache-SizeLimit-0.92-1.el6.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package mod_perl-2.0.4-10.el6.i686
```

Any ideas how I can solve that issue?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Kind regards, Matthias

Comment: What happens if you uninstall the mod_perl module then install the perl-apache-sizelimit, and see if it installs dependencies as necessary?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't uninstall mod_perl, as I need it for another application that is running on that server :(

Comment: If the machine is backed up, you can try the uninstall then installing the other module to see if that other module will re-install mod-perl as a dependency. If it doesn't, you can try reinstalling it after getting the sizelimit module installed. If everything gets borked, you can restore from backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you can do if you want since it is only a man page it is saying is a conflict.. Download the perl-Apache-SizeLimit rpm and force the install

```
wget http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/perl-Apache-SizeLimit-0.92-1.el6.rf.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh --force perl-Apache-SizeLimit-0.92-1.el6.rf.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: thx, that did the trick!